# how to copy song from iPod Library into your app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I dont want to select again n again the same sound to play as background in my app. How can i copy sound file into my app assigned folders/files?
I can play file in the method mediaPicker:didPickMediaItems:
How to save that sound file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPMediaItem` and `MPMediaItemCollection` both support `NSCoding`, so you should be able to serialize it and store it using `NSKeyedArchiver`, see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).  If `obj` is whatever object supporting `NSCoding`,

```
           NSData*data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
```

converts it to an `NSData` instance. Or, you can get the persistent ID [`MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID) of a song by

```
           NSNumber*persistentID=[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
```

and then yo ucan save the persistentID into somewhere, like `NSUserDefaults`.