# Access iPhone User Songs and Videos?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was wondering if I can access user's songs and videos in iPhone, part of that access if I can save them or modify them? hopefully not a Jailbroken iPhones

I am greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KanKoon: are you targeting Jailbroken iPhones?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer @badgerr @Hanuman: Thanks, all the answers are great I will start implementing the code immeditly and see which one will get the result correctly for me, I will be back to you asap, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I can't speak for video, because I've only done it for audio, but you can definitely get audio data. These links should get you started. Note: I am as yet unsure if this works with tracks that use any kind of iTunes-related DRM.

First of all, [this blog post](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/) talks you through the method of accessing the data. Note the reliance on iOS 4.1 or above.

[This SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972677/reading-audio-samples-via-avassetreader) explains how to get at the raw pcm data, should you want to do more than just save it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the user to pick songs using the [MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class. I think you can save the selected item to your app's sandbox directory.

You can read up on this a bit more with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166789/how-to-copy-song-from-ipod-library-into-your-app).

Comment: Thanks for response I will have a look at that and will back to you asap.